# Display all the in store pickup location on checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, store-pickup

I want to display all the enabled pickup location of magento' dedault in store pickup method. I was able to find file which returns the location Magento\InventoryInStorePickup\Model\GetPickupLocations.php . I am unable to return the colleciton here . Any help will be appreciated .